# Using DEmanager to update/insert to two Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to update/insert using Marketing Cloud's DEManager to two different data extension? They both have the attribute that I need to update. This data extension will be used differently that's why I need to update to both.

This is my sample code:

```html
<form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post" id="main-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="xxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="de1EXTERNALKEY/de2EXTERNALKEY">
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add/update">
    <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0">
```

I tried this one but I'm getting an error, I also tried

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="de1EXTERNALKEY|de2EXTERNALKEY">
```

and this one

```html
<form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post" id="main-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="xxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="de1EXTERNALKEY">
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="de2EXTERNALKEY">
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add/update">
    <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0">
```

Anyway, It's already working if I only update to one data extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEManager**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5) only works with a single data extension.

It may be a little tricky handling the response from DEManager, but you should be able to use [**AJAX**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324058/812377) (using the DEManager URL instead of some other PHP handler) to perform two posts upon form submission. -- otherwise, you'll have to do one at a time.